# Customisations to the TabularInline in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models e.g. `Book` and `Author`. An author can have many books and therefore I have a foreign-key from the `Book` to the `Author` table.

I display the the `Book` and the `Author` record in my Django application using the `TabularInline` class. This works fine but I get the a `Book object` on the top-left corner of every book row displayed in the author's inline admin. How can I remove this? I'm trying to avoid editing the Django admin templates if possible and some have suggested that I should override the `__unicode__` method on the `Book` model but I would like to hide it entirely.

Is this possible?

My `Book` model also references another model called `Publisher`. The publisher's `__unicode__` value is displayed in one of the columns of book records in the `TabularInline` but I'd like to be able to link this to the admin page for that `Publisher` record instead of just displaying simple text.

What should I specify to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by you like to hide it completely?

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot for what you want to do in the second part of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just override the admin template to add some CSS ?

For example, in templates/admin/testapp/author/change_form.html:

```
{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <style type="text/css">
    fieldset.module td.original p { display:none; }
    </style>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

You may do that [globally, per app or per model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates).

It works and seems pretty safe, unlike overriding the fieldset template itself - which makes sense to avoid doing.

Comment: Thanks JPic, that worked. I don't see any way than using a template either. Would you know how to solve the second part of my question? Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, i just need you to post your models and admin source code.

Answer (score 1):

You cah hide "Book object" links with some JS added to the AdminSite. It should be something like:

```
django.jQuery('.dynamic-phone_set h3').hide();
```